# trying to use a state variable to make string uppercase

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not understanding how this useState from react works. I am just trying to make a button which updates the title using the .toUpperCase but it is failing. I don't understand how >> const  [Title, setTitle] = useState(title) << this  line is suppose to be. I tried looking at the docs but can't seem to grasp it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    
    
    const Unit = (props) =>{  
    
      return (
        <div>
          <p>Unit code = {props.unitcode}, Title = {props.title} </p>
    
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    const App = () => {
    
      const unitcode = ['COMP1010', 'COMP1750'] 
      const title = ['Fundamentals of Computer Science','Introduction to Business Information Systems'] 
      const  [Title, setTitle] = useState(title)
      
    
      return (
        <div>
             <Unit unitcode = {unitcode[0]} title = {title[0]} />
              <button onClick={() => setTitle(title.toUpperCase)}>
                    UP
              </button>       
             <Unit unitcode = {unitcode[1]} title = {title[1]} />
             
    
        </div>
        
      )
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to using parenthesis with `toUpperCase()` and calling it on a string instead of array, this might be closer to what you want:

```
const App = () => {
    const unitcode = ["COMP1010", "COMP1750"];
    const titles = [
        "Fundamentals of Computer Science",
        "Introduction to Business Information Systems"
    ];
    const [titleOne, setTitleOne] = useState(titles[0]);
    const [titleTwo, setTitleTwo] = useState(titles[1]);

    return (
        <div>
          <Unit unitcode={unitcode[0]} title={titleOne} />
          <button onClick={() => setTitleOne(titleOne.toUpperCase())}>UP</button>
          <Unit unitcode={unitcode[1]} title={titleTwo} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Yes! this is what I was trying to figure out. I was just not getting the syntax right and the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `toUpperCase()` on an array. It only works on `string` type. Also, if you wish to invoke `toUpperCase()`, you are missing `()`.